# Pandas drop duplicates in CSV

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have two CSV's. They contain the same columns, and data. One CSV has additional records added.

I want to have 1 CSV containing the new additional records, and drop all duplicate records.

I have:

```
import pandas as pd

rows = pd.read_csv('/home/test/Documents/rows.csv')
rowsadded = pd.read_csv('/home/test/Documents/rowsadded.csv')

joined = rows.append(rowsadded)
reduce = joined.drop_duplicates(subset=None, keep=False, inplace=False)
reduce.to_csv('/home/test/Documents/results.csv')
```

When I set Keep = False, all records are dropped and only the column names are kept.

Anyone have any advice on dropping the duplicate records after I have appended the CSV's?

**UPDATE** - Altering the code as follows, appends the new rows from 'rowsadded' CSV to 'rows':

```
reduce = joined.drop_duplicates(keep=False, inplace=True)
```

What am I doing wrong - I want to drop duplicates, keep only new rows and write that information to a new CSV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it all in one go

```
pd.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

Comment: Same results, only 1 record returned (the column names). Thanks though - I assumed concat would do something similar. But I choose to do append just to make sure all records were actually being appended (they are).

Comment: Worked thanks. This is so embarrassing (I had my join backwards)